# An Error Was Encountered You have not selected a database type to connect to

Tags: php

```html
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'walkmjcd_moneywk',
 'password' => 'q?P?Lf817H~y',
 'database' => 'walkmjcd_walkmoney',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['default']='';
```

An Error Was Encountered You have not selected a database type to connect to. Please ANyone help in this case How can i resolve this.

Comment: I don't know what framework this is (My guess is CI, Code Igniter `86.4% confidence` ) but I would suggest looking at their documentation.  The `dbprefix` part is kind of a give away.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, the db configuration you set at top and reset it at the bottom. Just remove the `$db['default']='';` and try.

Comment: Lol .. I didn't even see that.  I was more concerned with figuring out what framework it was.

Comment: Don't tell anyone but when I built my CI site, I wrote my own DB layer.  At the time `CI 2` they didn't support PDO.  And CI3 didn't seem likely at that point.  I actually thought about using Larval, but it wasn't mature enough at that point.  I did however re-use their config file, which is how I recognized it...

Comment: Oh I see. Yes currently `CI` has lot of db drivers and has pdo support as well.

Comment: This was like 5-6 years ago, we still use the CI site every day it does about 150 million searches for our clients...

Comment: CI is awesome framework. The upcoming CI 4 has big change and you can't migrate from old versions I think.

Comment: ypp i am also waiting for the CI4 to release, expecting some major changes.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove :

$db['default']='';